# How to trigger body.onclick when clicking on empty space

Tags: javascript, html

How to trigger `body.onclick` when clicking on empty space when the page is larger than the actual body size?

For example the body is 300X400 but the user maximized the window and the page is now 800X600. If user click outside the actual body area, the `onclick` will not work. How to trigger it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the event target to `document` instead of `body`, eg

```
document.addEventListener('click', eventListener, false);
```

Comment: Oh my, simply works :) I used `document.onclick = function (){}` works too... will accept answer once it allows thanks!

Comment: The problem with this solutions is that not only gets the event for "empty" spaces but for every element... i.e. if you an anchor this event will be triggered as well...

Comment: I wouldn't say that's necessarily a problem